# React Router browserHistory.push('/') not working on docker server, works locally

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux, react-router-redux

I have spent days trying to figure out this issue, and I have no idea what it could be. I have tested everything.

I have a ReactJS project setup locally, I have a login page which then redirects you to a page and then a couple of pages that require being logged in to view them. This all works perfectly locally. When I push it to the staging server that should be setup exactly like my environment, it's a docker environment, then this one piece of functionality breaks: when you login it doesn't change the URL to "/", it just stays on "/login". The footer and header both appear (they are only setup to show once logged in), so I am not sure why this is happening.

I can click the menu links and go to any page as expected, it seems to just be the automatic redirection that's not working.

The code (removed unrelated code):

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import {
    Alert,
} from 'react-bootstrap';
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import { login } from '../../Actions/login';

class LoginForm extends Component {
    static propTypes = {
        login: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
        loggedIn: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
        loggingIn: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
        error: PropTypes.bool,
    }

    static contextTypes = {
        router: PropTypes.object,
    };

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            email: null,
            password: null,
            invalidEmail: false,
            invalidPassword: false,
        };
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        if (nextProps.loggedIn) {
            this.context.router.push('/');
            //browserHistory.push('/');
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried both: `this.context.router.push('/');` and `browserHistory.push('/');`, both work locally, but neither work on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Try `this.context.router.history.push('/')`.
I had the same problem a while back, and this fixed it. I can't find any documentation on it, though.

Comment: I get: this.context.router.history is undefined

Comment: Do you get any errors when using `this.context.router.push('/');` or `browserHistory.push('/');`?

Comment: No those both work fine locally, but not on the server.. I'm not sure why it isn't working on what should be the same environment.

Comment: This problem appears to be when you do a production build. Dev works fine, not production.

Answer (score 0):

Same happened in our current stack which includes webpack2 (babel v6), react-router v4, react-router-redux v5alpha and history v4.

Some difference happened to the production bundle.
While routing works perfectly in dev env on webpack-dev-server (incl historyApiFallback) the production bundle served by nginx inside a docker container changes the url but stops there. @@router change action is dispatched though.

What solved the issue for us was the usage of the HOC wrapper `withRouter` around the App.

https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/withRouter.md

We suppose the issue went undetected in dev env cause the

```
import { AppContainer } from 'react-hot-loader'

if (module.hot) {
    module.hot.accept('./App', () => {
        const NextApp = require('./App').default
        ReactDOM.render(wrapedApp(NextApp, store), rootEl)
    })
}
```

rerendered irregardless.